# Data not visible when trying to save excel file using epplus

Tags: epplus

I am migrating an application which uses ClosedXML as dependency to epplus.
When I try saving the same file using epplus the data inside that excel file is not visible.
Also the size of the excel file reduces.

[Update] - If I try saving a file which was previously modified and saved using ClosedXML I am not able to see data in excel. But if I try saving the file which was created using epplus only then the issue is not visible.

Comment: If you open the closedxml generated file in Excel does it show the data?  Might want to post the code you are using to generate the file for both libraries.

Comment: If the excel sheet has not been modified with epplus after it was changed using closed xml it is showing data correctly in excel as well. Not sure but I think excel is getting confused because there are two sets of xml tags added to the files because of which excel is not able to read the xml after modification